# Create DSN file from Visual Studio Local Server

Tags: sql, vb.net, crystal-reports, odbc

I'm having trouble while creating a DSN file of my service-based database for Crystal Report.
I already tried to create through Administrative tools > System DSN > Add > SQL Server.
but I cannot locate my local server : `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`

Maybe I missed something, Can you give me an advice on how ?

links or advice will be appreciated .

Comment: I thought localdb is a file that sort of auto attaches to a new temporary server, not a running server you could find locally .. but then again DSN are essentially just a system centric connection string and quite outdated as a way of doing things- why not just skip the DSN part?

Comment: LocalDB is for development purposes. If you want a proper SQL Server instance then install SQL Server Express. You may also have to use a permanently attached database, rather than a data file that gets attached when you run your app. Not sure a DSN will support files attached on demand because they use ODBC and attaching on demand is a SqlClient thing.

Comment: I thought that maybe it's possible to create a DSN as a data source for my crystal report,